# How can i get the description of a GitHub repo?

Tags: github, github-api

Every *GitHub repository* has a **description** *field* and an optional **website** *field*. How can these fields *(of any GitHub repo)* be accessed using **AJAX**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Github provides API for fetching detailed information about a repository:

`https://api.github.com/repos/<organization>/<project>`

eg. https://api.github.com/repos/ruby/ruby

You can use plain simple jQuery to get the information you require:

```
$.ajax('https://api.github.com/repos/ruby/ruby').done(function(json) { 
   // You can access the description as json.description
   console.log(json.description);       
});
```

Comment: Glad it helped @wolfram77

Comment: I have a problem with my public repository, I get a 404 error. https://api.github.com/repos/Limraj/dicegame/ ; https://github.com/Limraj/dicegame

Comment: @KamilTomaszJarmusik looks like you might be using a trailing slash after the link: This works for me `https://api.github.com/repos/Limraj/dicegame` without the slash after `dicegame`. Adding a slash gives 404.

Answer (score 2):

On this [page](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax) of the *Select2* plugin. They are taking advantage of github's api to search repositories and retreive results as json.
The full github api is available [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/).

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get a repo description by this search query `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=<repo>+user:<username>`.